# Set pull request merge options per branch

Tags: git, github

My team has set up a Github workflow where we squash and merge pull requests against a develop branch and rebase and merge pull requests against master (the latter to keep commit order across deployments).

I can enable "Squash and merge" and "Rebase and merge" options from the Github settings for all branches, is there a way to have a **per-branch configuration**? e.g. only rebase and merge allowed against master, otherwise only squash and merge allowed

Could be a Github setting / Github action etc.

Comment: 2023, still a relevant question

Comment: @osynavets True. I tried and proposed an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since there does not seem to be a native feature to enforce different merge options on a per-branch basis within the repository settings, you might need to write a GitHub Actions to enforce specific merge strategies for branches.

You would create a GitHub Actions workflow file that runs on pull request events. Inside the workflow, you can write a script that checks the base branch of the pull request and fail the workflow if the pull request does not meet the merge strategy criteria.

For example::

```yaml
name: Enforce Merge Strategy
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  enforce:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check base branch and merge method
      run: |
        BASE_BRANCH="${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}"
        if [[ "$BASE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
          # Enforce "Rebase and Merge" for master; Fail if not
          # Logic here to check if it is a rebase and merge
          # For instance, check if the branch is up-to-date with 'master'
          if [[ "$BASE_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
            git fetch origin master
            UP_TO_DATE=$(git rev-list HEAD..origin/master --count)
            if [[ "$UP_TO_DATE" != "0" ]]; then
              echo "Branch is not up-to-date with master. Please update your branch."
              exit 1
            fi
          fi
        elif [[ "$BASE_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
          # Enforce "Squash and Merge" for develop; Fail if not
          # Logic to check if multiple commits exist in the pull request for 'develop'
          if [[ "$BASE_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
            git fetch origin ${{ github.head_ref }}
            NUMBER_OF_COMMITS=$(git rev-list origin/${{ github.head_ref }} ^origin/$BASE_BRANCH --count)
            if [[ "$NUMBER_OF_COMMITS" -le 1 ]]; then
              echo "Not enough commits for a squash. Please make multiple commits."
              exit 1
            fi
          fi
        else
          echo "Invalid base branch. Cannot proceed."
          exit 1
        fi
```

Comment: Woah, looks cool
I'm gonna discuss it with my team
Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this method forces that developer manually squash all commits in feature branch before merging into develop?

Comment: @osynavets Yes, the idea is to check if the developers did the right thing, before accepting the PR.